# Android: Read text file and grab the line following a specific word

Tags: java, android

Im trying to grab a piece of data on a line that follows a pre-set reference

here is my code so far which just grabs everything in the text

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnRead) {

        try {
            readfile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Problems: " + e.getMessage(), 1).show();
        }
    }

private void readfile() throws IOException {     

    String str="";
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();          
    InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.test);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));


    if (is!=null) { 

        while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) { 

            buf.append(str + "\n" );


        }               
    }       
    is.close(); 
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), buf.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

i have thought about adding something like this

```
if (str == "name:"){

   reader.readNextLine();

    }
else {
    (buf.append("Referance not found" + "\n"));
}
```

that way it finds the pre-set word and grabs the immediately following line
Obviously i cant do

```
readNextLine
```

so trying to find another simple way

Comment: you should try if (str.equals("name:")) i guess!

Comment: you should try if "name".equals(str))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you compare the reference adress not the value.

The operator `==` for comparation is valid only for primitive types. String is an object type.

To compare object types you should always used `equals` method or `compareTo` if object support it.

```
if("name".equals(str)) {
  reader.readNextLine();
} else {
  buf.append("Referance not found\n");
}
```

TIP:

The [StringBuffer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) is thread safe, you do not need it there. Better choice would be usinge of [StringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Comment: reader.readNextLine(); still comes up with an error which was my problem in the first place ... what im looking for is some way to tell it to read the next line

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered regex?

```
    String expression = "name: ";
CharSequence inputStr = input;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    // here's where you'd write code to grab the next x amount of information
} else {
   // not found
}
```

Alternatively, if you're accepting a fixed amount of information (e.g. the line is name: Max Power) then you can use string tokenizer/split, check if "name: " matches one of the tokens, and then grab the next two tokens which will be your name. You might also want to use something like equalsIgnoreCase rather than == for strings, as it won't produce your desired outcome!